# Mount /etc as overlay with / mounted as tmpfs overlay

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel, mount, overlayfs

I want to mount / as a tmpfs overlay, which is done in the initramfs and works fine. mount looks like this:

```
...
/dev/sda1 on /ro type ext4 (ro,relatime)
tmpfs-root on /rw type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=131072k)
overlay on / type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/ro,upperdir=/rw/upper,workdir=/rw/work)
...
```

Now during boot time I want certain directories like /etc to be overlays as well, but mounted to a persistent /backup partition. How can I achieve this? I tried this in /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/sda5 /backup ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
overlayfs /etc overlay defaults,lowerdir=/ro-etc,upperdir=/backup/upper,workdir=/backup/work 0 2
```

But this won't work. Any ideas what's wrong here?

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, but the last field of an fstab line is the fsck priority - I don't think fsck has any meaning / knows what to do for an overlayfs, so that line should end "0 0" rather than "0 2".